# Sold machinery weapons, is there a way to get them back?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

As the question asks.  I didn't really think about it at the time and just remembered after visiting Cid that they're upgradeable and unique.  Is there any way for me to recover the machinery weapons I sold?

I kept the circular saw but sold the bioblaster and the autocrossbow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You cant get them back until you start another game, whether NG+ or otherwise. Personal notes below are in *italics* below the section header.

## From to the Official Deluxe Ed. Guide (p.202-p.207):

### Upgraded by Cid

*Only the machinery can be sold with none of them can be bought back after being sold. None of the melee weapons in this list can be purchased in a store, only found or acquired during a quest / side-quest.*

*These weapons **are** carried over to NG+ in their current state at game conclusion with the exception of Ultima Blade, which reverts to Engine Blade III. However, **all weapons carried over also duplicate in NG+** as if they were never acquired and can be re-upgraded and then sold allowing the player to sell and keep the weapon at the same time*:

1. Engine Blade > *Engine Blade II* > *Engine Blade III* > **Ultima Blade**
2. Force Stealer > **Force Stealer II**
3. Drain Lance > *Drain Lance II* > **Drain Lance III**
4. Plunderers > **Plunderers II**
5. Valiant > **Valiant II**
6. Absorb Shield > **Absorb Shield II**
7. Auto Crossbow > **Auto Crossbow Plus**
8. Bioblaster > **Biolblaster Plus**
9. Circular Saw > **Circular Saw Plus**
10. Noiseblaster > **Noiseblaster Plus**
11. Drillbreaker > **Drillbreaker Plus**

### Collectible Only

*These can be sold but not bought (there are collectible weapons that can also be bought, but the below list cannot) If you sell them, they're gone (sorry).*

1. Balmung (sword)
2. Enhancer (sword)
3. Duel Code (greatsword)
4. Iron Duke (greatsword)
5. Dominator (greatsword)
6. Apocolypse (greatsword)
7. Dragon Lance (polearm)
8. Flayer (polearm)
9. Ulric's Kukris (daggers)
10. Organyx (daggers)
11. Vigilantes (daggers)
12. Executioner (firearm)
13. Hyper Magnum (firearm)
14. Death Penalty (firearm)
15. Wizard Shield (shield)
16. Aegis Shield (shield)
17. Ziedrich (shield)

### Pre-Order Bonus Only

*These **cannot** bought or sold, **do** carry into NG+, and **do not** duplicate.*

1. Mage Mashers (daggers)
2. Gae Bolg (polearm)
3. Masamune (greatsword)
4. Blazefire Saber (sword)

All other weapons can be purchased, sold, and repurchased.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy them back with selling carrots to the NPC by the garden in Cape something. I've gotten valiant so far from him. You can only grow 3 carrots at a time and the weapons cost 4. GL